# Finding a relation between number of columns and the number of rows in a binary array

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, binary, correlation

I got stuck in this question and hoped for a little help.

> I have  binary array $n \times m$ with $n \leq m$, where each column contains exactly one occurrence of $1.$
> Also all the vectors connecting entries of $A$ that contain $1$ are distinct. There is no restriction on the number of $1$'s in a row. I need to prove that $m \le 2n.$

I tried to draw some examples to see how I can reach this inequailty but I can't seem to find any way to do that. If I look at the first index of the vector for instance, I see  that I can have maximum $m-1$ so I tried to see for $m>2n$ if I can reach any contradiction but nothing too.

Any help?

Edit:
Adding an example of the matrix for $n=3, m=4$:
[image]

Edit 2:
The height differences between 1's in adjacent columns is in range:

{-(n-1),...,-1,0,...,n-2,n-1} = V |V|=2n-1 this difference can't repeat so m-1<=2n-1 -> m<=2n

Comment: What are *vectors connecting entries of A*? Do you mean *rows*?

Comment: for A=[a11,a12,..]  a11 the vector (1,1) and a12 is the vector (1,2) and so on

Comment: Hmm, then do I understand you correctly that this sentence in the question (*all the vectors connecting entries of A that contain 1 are distinct*) means "If $1=a_{ij}=a_{kl}$, then $(i,j)\neq(k,l)$"?

Comment: yes, in other words, i can say the aperiodic real auto-correlation is:
"C _(A,A) (τ_1,τ_2 )= m for τ_1=τ_2=0 and ≤1 otherwise"

Comment: I added an example in the question itself

Comment: Oh, great! That picture clarifies things a lot. It is definitely *not* what I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: i did found that i should have m(m-1) vectors overall, but i don't know if im in the right direction for the proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** instead of considering **all** connecting vectors $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$, it suffices to focus only on these for which $a=1$ - that is, only the ones connecting **consecutive** columns.

For a given $n\times m$ matrix with a single "1" per column,

1. How many connecting vectors of the form $(1,b)$ exist?
2. How many (not necessarily connecting) vectors of the form $(1,b)$ can fit into the matrix?